# Weinberg–Witten theorem in other dimensions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, spacetime-dimensions, poincare-symmetry

The [Weinberg–Witten theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinberg%E2%80%93Witten_theorem) was proven in $3+1$ spacetime dimensions. Has anyone extended this to arbitrary dimensions? In other words, the theorem in its form as given in the above link, with the only difference that one is working in $d+1$ dimensional spacetime.